# Query glue from aurora postgres

Tags: aws-glue, amazon-athena, amazon-aurora

I want to query a glue table from aurora postgres.

I can use postgres_fdw to redshift spectrum, but aurora doesnt include jdbc_fdw so i cant use that to go straight to Athena.

I mean I could set up a postgres in a ec2 for jdbc_fdw but I’d just do redshift spectrum at that point since I'm already paying for redshift anyways.

Any other options?